# Render multiple .RMD files into one output (R Flexdashboard)

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have multiple .Rmd flexdashboard files that all can be rendered fine into .html format. I want each of these flexdashboards to become a page in a final flexdashboard. Is this possible?

I also have the .html output files for the .rmd files, would it be easier to have each page in the main flexdashboard be a hyperlink to each of these?